# import data from pydev to postgresqll

Tags: python, sql, eclipse, postgresql, pydev

I am trying to move data from pydev on eclipse to postgresql using pgadmin4. Why is my code printing "Error %s % e"? In postgres, the testtest123 table is getting created but the data is not being uploaded there. Many thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in readCSV:
            new_data = [ row[19]]
            print (new_data)

con = None

try:
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE testtest123 (HY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtest123(new_data)")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM testtest123;")
    con.commit()
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    if con:
        con.rollback() 

    print ("Error %s % e")
    sys.exit(1)

finally:   
    if con:
        con.close()

print(" ".join(row))
out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in new_data:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of table `testtest123` already exists, postgres wont create it again.
Dont wrap multiple statements in one `try/except` block - this makes it hard for you to determine to identify the error.

For debugging purposes you could this:

```
import traceback

# ... your code ...

con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
cur = con.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE testtest123 (HY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtest123(new_data)")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM testtest123;")
    con.commit()
except:
    print ("Error:")
    traceback.print_exc()
    con.rollback() 
    sys.exit(1)
finally:   
    if con:
        con.close()
```